# PHP Populating Dropdown

Tags: php, html, loops, foreach, associative-array

I have an associative array filled with states and their abbreviations.  I'm trying to populate a dropdown with the key field of the associative php array.  However, I'm running into some snags when I'm trying to put the fields within their `<option>`s tag.
Here's what I have (minus the associative array).

```
<body>
    <select> 
        <?php
            foreach ($states as $key => $value) {
                echo "<option value="\ . $key . ">" . $key . "</option><br/>"; //Prints out the Abbreviation of the states
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</body>
```

I believe my escape sequence is correct.  I'm trying to put the key as the value for the HTML tag as well.  I'm not using MySQL for this, just an associative array I've created, so many resources I find online I really can't follow due to their use of MySQL.

I know what I'm missing is pretty simple, just can't pinpoint it.  Thanks for all you help.

Comment: what is the need of "\" ? if needed then put it within `"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Values of the html attributes should be wrapped in quotes and you don't need `<br/>` tag inside your dropdown list :

```
echo '<option value="' . $key . '">' . $key . '</option>';
```

There is another option :

```
echo "<option value=\"" . $key . "\">" . $key . "</option>";
```

And another :

```
 echo "<option value=\"$key\">$key</option>";
```